# After building release in Flutter Web, kReleaseMode is still false

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I build my deployment release via Docker.

```
command: ["flutter", "pub", "global", "run", "webdev", "serve", "--hostname", "0.0.0.0", "web:5001", "--release"]
```

I have defined part of the code which retrieve different value based on the environment. Either it's `production` or `development`.

```
import 'package:flutter_web/foundation.dart';
....
static getEnvironment() {
    if (kReleaseMode) {
      return "production";
    } else {
      return "development";
    }
  }
```

However, even after building a release build, after calling `getValue` method I receive `development` value.

What I do wrong here?